# Max Eigenvalue Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. The set $\mathcal{L}(X)$ of all linear mappings $A: X \to X$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. Prove, or disprove with a counterexample, the following assertion:

\begin{align*}
\rho(A) = \textrm{max}\{|\lambda| \in \mathbb{R} : \lambda \textrm{ is an eigenvalue of $A$}\}
\end{align*}
defines a norm on $\mathcal{L}(X)$.

It seems to me that this is not a norm. For a counterexample, consider any nonzero nilpotent operator $N$. Since $N$ is nilpotent, its only eigenvalues are 0, hence $\rho(N) = 0$. However, for $\rho$ to be a norm, $\rho(X) = 0$ if and only if $X = 0$, so $\rho$ is not a norm. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: You make a good point.

Comment: Of course, the question is if such a non-zero nilpotent operator exists. If you can give one, that would be the counterexample.

Comment: Good point. Would something like this work:

Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ be a nonzero operator on $X$. Since $X$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, there exists a decomposition,

$T = D + N$, where $D$ is a diagonalizable matrix and $N$ is a nilpotent matrix, $N$ is a suitable counterexample.

Comment: Your $N$ could be zero in that example and it always will be if $\operatorname{dim} X = 1$ (in fact in this case the map *is* a norm). For $\operatorname{dim} X > 1$ take e.g. two linearly independent vectors $v_1, v_2$ and define $N$ by $v_1\mapsto v_2, v_2\mapsto 0$ and extend $N$ by zero on a complement of $\operatorname{span} v_1,v_2$.

Comment: I see how $v_1 \mapsto v_2, v_2 \mapsto 0$ works, but I don't understand what you mean by "extend $N$ by zero on a complement of span $v_1,v_2$.

Comment: @leoli1 sorry if forgot to tag you in my question

Comment: The association $v_1\mapsto v_2,v_2\mapsto 0$ defines a non-zero operator on $\operatorname{span}v_1,v_2$ that squares to $0$. But we want to have such a map on all of $X$, therefore we write $X=Y\oplus \operatorname{span}v_1,v_2$ and define $N$ on $Y$ to be $0$. Then $N$ is defined on $X$ and still satisfies $N^2=0$.